# How do I write mathematical equations on this site?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

I can't find anything about this on the help page . So , how do people exactly write out these complex looking integration problems on a phone?
Is this the "mathjax" thing people talk about?

Comment: Yes, it is the MathJax thing.  A brief introduction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) has links to more detailed information.

Comment: In general, if you are stuck on something on the site, the first thing to try (after the help pages) is to look at what has been posted on Meta with the [meta-tag:faq] tag.